# SELECT rows from table PLUS rows pertaining to selected rows in one query

Tags: mysql, join, union

Is there a way to retrieve a set of rows from a table but also including (join, union?) rows from the same table whose ids are referenced in the initial selection? Here's an example.

```
ID       Name       Surname         UserID    ParentID
---------------------------         ------------------
1        Daniel     Brown           1         0
2        John       Brown           2         4
3        Andrew     Brown           3         5
4        Simon      Smith           4         0
5        Peter      Smith           5         1
```

So I want to retrieve all the rows where the surname is Brown, and also all the rows pertaining to the parent value. In this example, all rows would be returned.

I would like to do this in one query, if it's possible. Note, I would not want to return Peter Smith's parent row (1) as well. Just the initial search (all the Browns) and the relevant parents to that initial search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bff130c3c1e3b86335026972527466bc)**

```
select id,name,surname,parent from tablename
where surname='Brown'
union 
select a1.id,a1.name,a1.surname,a1.parent from tablename a join tablename a1
on a.parent=a1.id
where a.surname='Brown'
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  name    surname parent
1   Daniel  Brown   0
2   John    Brown   5
3   Andrew  Brown   4
4   Simon   Smith   0
5   Peter   Smith   1
```

Comment: Ignore the previous comment; +1; you need UNION instead of UNION ALL, because duplicates may appear, if more people have same parent

Comment: This is great, but I may have over-simplified the question, as in reality, the parentID column is being joined from a separate table, so is unavailable for the union. I will update the question to reflect the slightly more complex situation.